# How to make view mode available only to selected bundle?

Tags: 8, entities

I have three taxonomy vocabularies which means that I have three bundles of the vocabulary entity type. I have a few view modes for them and one of them has to be available only to one of those vocabularies.

The method responsible for getting available view modes is `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager::getAllDisplayModesByEntityType()` but it does not distinct between bundles, only entity types.

Is there a way I can make that view mode restricted for that one particular vocabulary or this is just not possible?

Comment: I do not have an answer per-say, but how large of a data set are you looking at? Would it be too intensive to load all the entities returned by that method to find the taxonomy vocabularies you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. A view mode is not bundle-specific.

That hardly matters, because a view mode doesn't do anything unless you actually enable it and configure field formatters for it, resulting in a view display. If you don't then it just falls back to the default view display.

Comment: The reason for my question is that that specific view mode make sense only for one for my vocabularies. I guess I'll have to rename it to something more generic then. Thanks.